# Easiest and quickest way to transfer heat?

Tags: thermodynamics

If I have a heat source like a heater or something. And want to transfer most of that heat to the air in a very small and closed system, preferably within seconds or even milliseconds, what would be the best solution? Any answer would help. I was thinking if I cooled the air down to around $12^\circ F$ or lower, the heat would transfer faster. I want to create a heating system like a stove, but not a stove and more efficient and which works faster, but that's not really important.

Comment: Could you really streamline your query?

Comment: Radiant heat (at the speed of light) is fast, but 'transfer most of that heat to the air' is slow.   To get heat to air, or away from a source, we need to know more about the source and/or the airspace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do with the system *is* important.  It's important because the usual answer is forced air cooling.  You want a radiator and to blow lots of air across it.

[image: Radiator]

However, there's a problem:

> And want to transfer most of that heat to the air in a very small and closed system, preferably within seconds or even milliseconds

Thermodynamics will not be your friend.  Temperatures try to equalize.  In order to transfer "most" of the heat, you need to transfer it to something that has a much greater heat capacity than your heat source.  Air doesn't have a very high heat capacity, so you're going to have to push a lot of air past it.  A lot of air

[image: 1x1]

That's the test chamber of [NASA's 1x1 wind tunnel](https://www1.grc.nasa.gov/facilities/1x1/).  It goes up to mach 6.  That lets you push a *lot* of air across your object, transferring heat quickly.  Of course, at those speeds, the friction effects are so high that you might increase the heat of your object instead...

Which goes back to the original statement.  What you are trying to do *does* matter here, because it affects what the right solution is.  Generally speaking, you will not be able to transfer most of the heat out of an object into the air in seconds, unless your object is *very* thin (a piece of aluminum foil, heated to red hot in a flame, transfers most of its heat out into the air in moments... but it didn't have very much heat to begin with).

Your best approach may be to put the heat directly into the area.  The typical approach to heating air is something like this:

[image: Air heater]

The approach here is pretty simple.  It's pretty easy to transfer most of the heat into the air if the heat is *created* in the air, via burning fuels.

But again, it all depends on what you are actually trying to do.

Comment: I am sorry i didn't ask a question with more details. I don't really know how to explain it without giving it away and tgat would create problems when i go to patent. But you answer my question perfectly even if you didn't know. Sorry again and next time i will plan my question out better.